# Java SQL resultset retrieval order is not correct

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following three row in my table say tb1

```
key   time   id   rowid
X     11:40  1      1
Y     4:50   1      2
Z     6:48   1      2
```

Now I am using JDBC to get records and iterating over resultset as shown below:

```
rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from tb1")
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int cols = md.getColumnCount();
while(rs.next())
{
   for(int i = 1; i <= cols ; i++)
   {
     System.out.println("col name " + md.getColumnName(i));
     System.out.println("col name " + rs.getObject(i));
   }

}
```

When I execute the above code strangely it always prints second row first and then first row and then third row. In short resultset data retrieval is not in order. Why is this?

Comment: Why should they be in order? Since you do not include an `order by` clause in your query the order is undefined.

Comment: Does the same happen when you use an `order by`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not specified an "order by" clause.  In general, databases are not required to return rows in any order unless an "order by" clause is specified.  Add an order by clause to your select statement.

Comment: Hi thanks for the input. In database table rows are exactly same as written here so resultset also should return rows as is. Or its not like that?

Comment: A relational database can return the rows in the same order in which they were inserted, but without an "order by" clause, it certainly does not have to do so.

Comment: I faced same issue some time ago. The result set returned by native sql from hibernate and toad were not in same order. so rgettman is right. use "order by" statement.

Comment: Order by what? When I want the columns in the order they were defined, as per above Key - Time - id - rowid, where would I put the 'Order By' anyway? I don't need to order the rows, in my case I use 'select  top 1 * from table' , followed by the 'getMetaData()' on a table with 12 columns and the columns arrive in the wrong order. Unless I'm missing something I don't see a good answer here.