# MySQL- How to fetch multiple values of same column using a single SQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset

I need to store each values from the Resultset to float variables. Currently I am using multiple SQL queries for this. I have combined the queries

```
float Wb_SWLat = 0;
float Wb_NELat = 0;
float Wb_SWLon = 0;
float Wb_NELon = 0;

float Nb_SWLat = 0;
float Nb_NELat = 0;
float Nb_SWLon = 0;
float Nb_NELon = 0;

//Query:
String qryWb = "select zone, SW_lat, SW_lon, NE_lat, NE_lon from tbl_zones";

try {
    Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

    Wb=stmt.executeQuery(qryWb);
    while(Wb.next()){ 
        if (Wb.getString("zone") == "west"){
            Wb_SWLat=Wb.getFloat("SW_lat");
            Wb_NELat=Wb.getFloat("NE_lat");
            Wb_SWLon=Wb.getFloat("SW_lon");         
            Wb_NELon=Wb.getFloat("NE_lon");
        }
        else if (Wb.getString("zone") == "north"){
            Nb_SWLat=Wb.getFloat("SW_lat");
            Nb_NELat=Wb.getFloat("NE_lat");
            Nb_SWLon=Wb.getFloat("SW_lon");         
            Nb_NELon=Wb.getFloat("NE_lon");
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is this is the efficient way? or right way of doing this?

Below is My MySQL table, tbl_zones:-

```
pk_id  jn    zone     SW_lat     SW_lon     NE_lat     NE_lon
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1     j1    west     9.99404    76.3567    9.99419    76.3572
 2     j2    north    9.99419    76.3572    9.99471    76.3573
 3     j3    south    9.99384    76.3572    9.99413    76.3573
 4     j4    east     9.99413    76.3574    9.99426    76.3577
```

Comment: Dear programmers, Any piece of code is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OR` operator in the `where` clause. That will get you **both** lines needed in **one** query (and [roundtrip time to DB](http://database-programmer.blogspot.co.il/2010/12/cost-of-round-trips-to-server.html?m=1)).

Now, in order to identify each fetched line, add `zone` to your `select` statement, and use an `if` clause in your code to identify the current line in the `ResultSet` object.

The query should look something like this:

```
select SW_lat, SW_lon, NE_lat, NE_lon, zone from tbl_zones where zone='west' OR zone='north
```

Comment: I'm Sorry i did'nt really get that! I want to get "SW_lat", "SW_lon", "NE_lat" and "NE_lon" of west and north separately. i.e eight separate values as shown in the program.

Comment: @jasim you can iterate through the fetched lines in the `ResultSet`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643576/java-looping-through-result-set).

Comment: yes i can. If your go through my program, you can see that i'm iterating using  "Wb.getFloat("SW_lat")" where wb is the resultset

Comment: Not through **variables** in the `ResultSet`, but through **lines**. That will help you use the two fetched lines. Understand?

Comment: I have modified the query as "select SW_lat, SW_lon, NE_lat, NE_lon from tbl_zones" and i have iterated the values of the first row   Wb_SWLat=Wb.getFloat(1);
  Wb_NELat=Wb.getFloat(2);
  Wb_SWLon=Wb.getFloat(3);   
  Wb_NELon=Wb.getFloat(4); but when i tried fetch the values from second column, i.e north "  Nb_SWLat=Wb.getFloat(5);" code is not working

Comment: Select "zone" too, and you it as a identifier of each line, as [you can't depend on order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109936/java-sql-resultset-retrieval-order-is-not-correct).

Comment: @jasim don't `getFloat(5).` As you don't have 5 `float`s in your current result. Move to the **next line** in the `ResultSet` - `wb.next()` - abd go through 1-4 again.

Comment: i got it. How about this:-   if(Wb.next()){ 

  if (Wb.getString("zone") == "west"){
   Wb_SWLat=Wb.getFloat("SW_lat");
   Wb_NELat=Wb.getFloat("NE_lat");
   Wb_SWLon=Wb.getFloat("SW_lon");   
   Wb_NELon=Wb.getFloat("NE_lon");
  }
  else if (Wb.getString("zone") == "north"){
   Wb_SWLat=Wb.getFloat("SW_lat");
   Wb_NELat=Wb.getFloat("NE_lat");
   Wb_SWLon=Wb.getFloat("SW_lon");   
   Wb_NELon=Wb.getFloat("NE_lon");
  } }

Comment: Wb is the result set, is the above method is efficient way of iterating all the data? I have updated my code in the answer, please go through and reply

Comment: Efficient? Yes. Pretty? Not so much. But for the scope of this question - it's enough. If you found my answer as helpful, please mark it ad accepted.

Comment: @jasim and edit your question, you missed a code line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern. sure i will put tick for you. but i will be happy to know what is the pretty efficient method?

Comment: @jasim pretty = remove code duplication + encapsulate the float extraction in a method that gets a line if results and returns a composite data-structure...

Comment: @jasim BTW accepting an answer != upvoting it. I think accepting is **far** more important, for future reference, for example.

Comment: Sounds pretty complicated for me. what ever my current code is not working

Comment: the function "if (Wb.getString("zone") == "west"){//iterate values}" not working!! if you help me to get it right, ill definitely accept as it is inside the scope of my question

Comment: @jasim use equals.

Comment: you mean "=" instead of "==" ?

Comment: No. Use: String zone = Wb.getString("zone"); then if(zone != null && zone.equals("west"))

Comment: You have the Tick :) It works. Thanks a lot & i changed the if to while loop for iterating the resultset. AnywaY thank you very much for the 'Pretty'. I'll think about it later.